# how to set autoincrement with trigger in sqlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, triggers

Guys i just want to ask how about creating trigger to make autoincrement in my field of database, this is my :

DBHelper.java

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
public static final String TABLE_NAME                   = "sma";
public static final String COLUMN_ID                    = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_NAMA_SMA              ="nama_sma";
public static final String COLUMN_ALAMAT_SMA            ="alamat_sma";
public static final String COLUMN_LATITUDE_SMA          ="latitude_sma";
public static final String COLUMN_LONGITUDE_SMA         ="longitude_sma";
public static final String COLUMN_TELEPON_SMA           ="telepon_sma";
public static final String COLUMN_WEBSITE_SMA           ="website_sma";
public static final String COLUMN_EMAIL_SMA             ="email_sma";
public static final String COLUMN_TANGGAL_BERDIRI_SMA   ="tanggal_berdiri_sma";
public static final String COLUMN_DESKRIPSI_SMA         ="deskripsi_keunggulan_sma";
public static final String COLUMN_TANGGAL_AKREDITASI    = "tanggal_akreditasi";
public static final String COLUMN_FACEBOOK              ="facebook_sma";
public static final String COLUMN_TWITTER               ="twitter_sma";
//foreign key
public static final String COLUMN_FK_ID_BATASAN_USIA    ="id_batasan_usia";
public static final String COLUMN_FK_ID_AKREDITASI      ="id_akreditasi";
public static final String COLUMN_FK_ID_LOKASI          ="id_lokasi";
public static final String COLUMN_FK_ID_KURIKULUM       ="id_kurikulum";
public static final String COLUMN_FK_ID_BIAYA           ="id_biaya";


private static final String db_name ="schoolmap.db";
private static final int db_version=1;
private static final String db_create = "create table "
      + TABLE_NAME + "("
      + COLUMN_ID                   + " integer primary key autoincrement, "  
      + COLUMN_NAMA_SMA             + " varchar(20) not null, "  
      + COLUMN_ALAMAT_SMA           + " varchar(30) not null, "  
      + COLUMN_LATITUDE_SMA         + " varchar(10) not null, "  
      + COLUMN_LONGITUDE_SMA        + " varchar(10) not null, "  
      + COLUMN_TELEPON_SMA          + " varchar(15) null, "  
      + COLUMN_WEBSITE_SMA          + " varchar(20) null, "  
      + COLUMN_EMAIL_SMA            + " varchar(20) null, "  
      + COLUMN_TANGGAL_BERDIRI_SMA  + " datetime not null, "
      + COLUMN_DESKRIPSI_SMA        + " varchar(30) null, " 
      + COLUMN_TANGGAL_AKREDITASI   + " datetime not null, "
      + COLUMN_FACEBOOK             + " varchar(10) , " 
      + COLUMN_TWITTER              + " varchar(10), " 
      + COLUMN_FK_ID_BATASAN_USIA   + " integer DEFAULT 1, "
      + COLUMN_FK_ID_AKREDITASI     + " integer, "  
      + COLUMN_FK_ID_LOKASI         + " integer, "
      + COLUMN_FK_ID_KURIKULUM      + " integer, "
      + COLUMN_FK_ID_BIAYA          + " integer);"; 


 public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, db_name, null, db_version);
    // Auto generated
   }
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL(db_create);

     //This code isn't working, is the code wrong? 
     db.execSQL("CREATE TRIGGER pk AFTER INSERT ON sma " +
    "BEGIN " +
    "UPDATE sma SET id_batasan_usia = id_batasan_usia + 1 " +
    "END");
 }
}
```

The Trigger isn't working, when i run first time COLUMN_FK_ID_LOKASI, and COLUMN_FK_ID_BIAYA is set default to 0, but after i insert data for the second, it's must be 1 right? I'm never using trigger before, so I really need help this time, can anybody help me? Thank you :D

Comment: COLUMN_ID already is autoincrementing. Why do you think you need a trigger? (And there is a syntax error in your trigger.)

Comment: @CL.: yup, but i need to auto incrementing COLUMN_FK_ID_LOKASI, and COLUMN_FK_ID_BIAYA, it only can be done with trigger right?

Comment: A foreign key refers to an existing record in another table; inventing a new value would not make sense.

Comment: @CL.: okay now I just edit my code, now how about make autoincrement with the trigger?

Comment: And what should the new values in these columns be?

Comment: @CL.: the first time i insert on table sma, the column id_batasan_usia, and id_lokasi will set the value into 0, then when i insert data on second time, i want id_batasan_usia, and id_lokasi will set value to 1,2, and so on(autoincrement) how can i do this with trigger?

Answer (score 0):

To set some column's value to a value that is larger than any other values already in the table, use a trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER autoinc_sma_lokasi
AFTER INSERT ON sma
WHEN NEW.lokasi IS NULL
BEGIN
    UPDATE sma
    SET lokasi = IFNULL((SELECT MAX(lokasi) FROM sma) + 1, 0)
    WHERE _id = NEW._id;
END;
```

Comment: can i ask, NEW.lokasi == id_lokasi right? and what mean id = NEW.id?

Comment: No, you must use the primary key of the table to update the same row that got inserted.